# mysql: need null fields when join doesn't match

Tags: mysql

I´m strugling with these two tables on MySQL.

```
select emp_id, contrato_id,date from organização_rh;
+--------+-------------+------------+
| emp_id | contrato_id | date       |
+--------+-------------+------------+
|      1 |           1 | 2000-01-01 |
|      1 |           2 | 2000-01-10 |
|      1 |           3 | 2000-02-01 |
|      2 |           1 | 1999-01-01 |
+--------+-------------+------------+

select id, codigo from contratotipo;
+----+---------------+
| id | codigo        |
+----+---------------+
|  2 | determinado   |
|  3 | fim           |
|  1 | indeterminado |
+----+---------------+
```

What I’m trying to do is to join them in a way that where an employee didn’t sign a contract the date field is set to NULL. That is, I’d like to have an output as the following:

```
+--------+-------------+------------+
| emp_id | contrato_id | date       |
+--------+-------------+------------+
|      1 |           1 | 2000-01-01 |
|      1 |           2 | 2000-01-10 |
|      1 |           3 | 2000-02-01 |
|      2 |           1 | 1999-01-01 |
|      2 |           2 | NULL       |
|      2 |           3 | NULL       |
+--------+-------------+------------+
```

I’ve tried different joins to no avail, and, so far, none of them shows me a row with a NULL value in the date field. So, for example if I run

```
SELECT emp_id,contrato_id, date 
FROM organização_rh as o right outer JOIN contratotipo c
ON o.contrato_id = c.id;
```

I don't get any NULL values when rows don’t match.

```
 +--------+-------------+------------+
 | emp_id | contrato_id | date       |
 +--------+-------------+------------+
 |      1 |           3 | 2000-02-01 |
 |      1 |           2 | 2000-01-10 |
 |      1 |           1 | 2000-01-01 |
 |      2 |           1 | 1999-01-01 |
 +--------+-------------+------------+
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

@John Ruddell thanks for your help. 
I came up with this solution that is not that elegant as it uses cursors, but it works with any number of employees and contracts. Your solution seems more alegant as everything fits in a just one query. However, I wasn't able to adapted it to a more general case.

```
BEGIN
declare var_contrato_id int unsigned;
declare contrato_finished int default 0;


DECLARE contrato_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM contratotipo;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET contrato_finished = 1;  
OPEN contrato_cursor;

drop table if exists temp_sp_rh_turnover;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_sp_rh_turnover AS (select distinct org_id, emp_id, cast( 0 AS unsigned) as contrato_id, cast('1000-1-1' as date) as data from organização_rh where emp_id=-1);

conts: LOOP

    FETCH contrato_cursor INTO var_contrato_id;
    IF contrato_finished = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE conts;
    END IF;
    insert into temp_sp_rh_turnover
    select distinct org_id, emp_id, var_contrato_id, NULL from organização_rh;

end loop;


select
    t.org_id, t.emp_id, t.contrato_id, o.data
from
    temp_sp_rh_turnover as t
left join
    organização_rh as o
on
    t.org_id = o.org_id and
    t.emp_id = o.emp_id and
    t.contrato_id = o.contrato_id;



drop table if exists temp_sp_rh_turnover;
END
```

Comment: You don't get `NULL` cause all rows matches between two tables.

Comment: this is not something you can just do in mysql. you need to alter your table to handle a request like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something like this is not easy in mysql and itll require a lot of manual work. from what I understand you want to show a new row per row in your other table..

meaning
for **every** `emp_id` in table o, you want there to be 3 rows related to it, one relating to each of the three rows in table c.

now to do something like that is not simple at all since there is no way to manually add rows, unless you are doing an insert or a bunch of unions. so with this dataset (which im assuming is small compared to what you are working with) you can get those desired results like this.

```
SET @row_num := 1;

INSERT INTO organização_rh (emp_id, contrato_id, date)
SELECT 
    emp_id, @ROW_NUM := @ROW_NUM + 1, NULL
FROM organização_rh
WHERE emp_id IN
(   SELECT emp_id 
    FROM organização_rh
    GROUP BY emp_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
)
AND @ROW_NUM < 3;
```

run this insert query twice and i'll give you the output you want.

**OUTPUT:**

```
23:20:25    set @row_num := 1   0 row(s) affected   0.000 sec
23:20:30    INSERT INTO organização_rh (emp_id, contrato_id, date) SELECT      emp_id, @ROW_NUM := @ROW_NUM + 1, NULL FROM organização_rh WHERE emp_id IN ( SELECT emp_id   FROM organização_rh  GROUP BY emp_id  HAVING COUNT(*) < 3 ) AND @ROW_NUM < 3    1 row(s) affected Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0    0.001 sec
23:20:31    INSERT INTO organização_rh (emp_id, contrato_id, date) SELECT      emp_id, @ROW_NUM := @ROW_NUM + 1, NULL FROM organização_rh WHERE emp_id IN ( SELECT emp_id   FROM organização_rh  GROUP BY emp_id  HAVING COUNT(*) < 3 ) AND @ROW_NUM < 3    1 row(s) affected Records: 1  Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0 0.001 sec
23:20:32    INSERT INTO organização_rh (emp_id, contrato_id, date) SELECT      emp_id, @ROW_NUM := @ROW_NUM + 1, NULL FROM organização_rh WHERE emp_id IN ( SELECT emp_id   FROM organização_rh  GROUP BY emp_id  HAVING COUNT(*) < 3 ) AND @ROW_NUM < 3    0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0    0.002 sec
```

if you notice the last time i tried to do it it wouldn't do it because the row num was max'd out. this will be some manual labor but its basically the only way to do it solely in mysql.

after inserting this is the result set.

```
+-------+---------------+---------------+
|emp_id |  contrato_id, |      date     |
+-------+---------------+---------------+
|'1',   |      '1',     |   '2000-01-01'|
|'1',   |      '2',     |   '2000-01-10'|
|'1',   |      '3',     |   '2000-02-01'|
|'2',   |      '1',     |   '1999-01-01'|
|'2',   |      '2',     |    NULL       |
|'2',   |      '3',     |    NULL       |
+-------+---------------+---------------+
```

**NOTE:** this is for updating the table. if you wanted **just a query with this output**, you will need to union a new row for each one which isn't really recommended. to be honest you need to fix your table structure. add a column that you could do a cartesian product join on or something.

anyways here is the union query.

```
SELECT emp_id, contrato_id, date FROM organização_rh
CROSS JOIN(SELECT @ROW_NUM := 0)t
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    emp_id, @ROW_NUM := @ROW_NUM + 1, NULL
FROM
    organização_rh
WHERE emp_id IN
(   SELECT emp_id 
    FROM organização_rh
    GROUP BY emp_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
)
AND @ROW_NUM < 3
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
    emp_id, @ROW_NUM := @ROW_NUM + 1, NULL
FROM
    organização_rh
WHERE emp_id IN
(   SELECT emp_id 
    FROM organização_rh
    GROUP BY emp_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
)
AND @ROW_NUM < 3;
```

**OUTPUT** is again the same as the insert

```
+-------+---------------+---------------+
|emp_id |  contrato_id, |      date     |
+-------+---------------+---------------+
|'1',   |      '1',     |   '2000-01-01'|
|'1',   |      '2',     |   '2000-01-10'|
|'1',   |      '3',     |   '2000-02-01'|
|'2',   |      '1',     |   '1999-01-01'|
|'2',   |      '2',     |    NULL       |
|'2',   |      '3',     |    NULL       |
+-------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: no problem :) i would recommend you make a users table or something that you can use to get those null values in a left join. i can post what I would recommend if you want.

Comment: @user3889486 you need to reset the `@row_count` for each new user.

Comment: Thanks  for the post. I'm gonna post a new message belog as I'm having some issues adding comments here.

Comment: @user3889486 you can edit your question as well if you would like

Answer (score 0):

Outer join the table to itself.  Something like:

```
select emp_id, contrato_id,date from organização_rh as a
JOIN
SELECT DISTINCT contrato_id FROM organização_rh as b
WHERE a.contrato_id = b.contrato_id
```

should work.

Alternatively you could

```
select emp_id, contrato_id,date from organização_rh as a
JOIN
select DISTINCT id from contratotipo as b
WHERE a.contrato_id = b.id
```

If thats more to your liking.

Comment: Np, didn't try it but outer join seems to be what he/she's looking for in the example.

Comment: I tried this one, but it doesn't show rows with NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having trouble is that you cannot accomplish this without a third table listing all employees.

You might argue that you could get this information with

```
select distinct emp_id from organização_rh
```

but this would not cover the case where there is an employee that has not signed ANY contracts.  Certainly you would want that employee to appear in the output with null dates for all contracts.

Create an `employee` table and then the join should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

@John Ruddell

This works great with the original values.
I added a new employee: emp_id=3, contrato_id=1, date=2001-1-1. If I run the query, I get that contract 3 (for emp_id=3)is missing.

```
|emp_id|contrato_id|   date     |
+------+-----------+------------+
|'1',  | '1',      |'2000-01-01'|
|'1',  | '2',      |'2000-01-10'|
|'1',  | '3',      |'2000-02-01'|
|'2',  | '1',      |'1999-01-01'|
|'2',  | '2',      | NULL       |
|'2',  | '3',      | NULL       |
|'3',  | '1',      |'2001-01-01'|
|'3',  | '2',      | NULL       |
```

Do I have to run the query:

```
SELECT 
    emp_id, @ROW_NUM := @ROW_NUM + 1, NULL
FROM
    organização_rh

WHERE emp_id IN
 (   SELECT emp_id 
    FROM organização_rh
    GROUP BY emp_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
)
AND @ROW_NUM < 3
```

for each user after resetting @ROW_NUM?

Comment: this should be an edit to your post not another answer. however for user 3 you need to reset `@ROW_NUM` back to 0. run the SET query first and then the user 3 update.